# Replacing a diode

Tags: diodes

I have a 24V battery charger that got wired in backwards and it fried one of the diodes. The codes on the diode are:

```
STPS30
150CW
U4D409
```

I have found one which I think should work, but could someone with a bit more knowledge please check it for me?

http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/rectifier-schottky-diodes/4858140P/

Answer (score 1):

It has the same part number. Of course it would work.

Anyway, if you couldn't find exactly the same diode you would have looked for a diode with:

- a current rating equal or greater than the original one
- a reverse voltage equal or greater than the original one

You could even use two single diodes instead of it (of course with the same or greater ratings).